# Free website for identifying influential or contentious US state and local court cases?

Tags: usa, government, database, legal, state

I am looking for free websites that contain (potentially partial) catalogs of state and local court cases in the United States, and allows me to filter and/or sort by any of the following:

```
The vote margin
Some kind of expert/subjective/automated/experimental measure of the case's influence
Some kind of objective measure of how often the case was cited
Some kind of expert/subjective/automated/experimental measure of the case's political contentiousness
```

Does anything like this exist? My intent is to be able to look for things like "top 5 most politically sensitive cases in bla county superior court from 2000-2010." Determinations like that would be deeply subjective, but maybe subject to some kind of systematic approach?